# How to use System.Net.HttpClient to post a complex type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom complex type that I want to work with using Web API.

```
public class Widget
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my web API controller method. I want to post this object like so:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // POST /api/test
    public HttpResponseMessage<Widget> Post(Widget widget)
    {
        widget.ID = 1; // hardcoded for now. TODO: Save to db and return newly created ID

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage<Widget>(widget, HttpStatusCode.Created);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, "/api/test/" + widget.ID.ToString());
        return response;
    }
}
```

And now I'd like to use `System.Net.HttpClient` to make the call to the method. However, I'm unsure of what type of object to pass into the `PostAsync` method, and how to construct it. Here is some sample client code.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new StringContent("???"); // how do I construct the Widget to post?
client.PostAsync("http://localhost:44268/api/test", content).ContinueWith(
    (postTask) =>
    {
        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    });
```

How do I create the `HttpContent` object in a way that web API will understand it?

Comment: Have you tried submitting an XML serialized version of your object to the service endpoint?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The generic `HttpRequestMessage<T>` has been **removed**. This :

```
new HttpRequestMessage<Widget>(widget)
```

will **no longer work**.

Instead, [from this post](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350492), the ASP.NET team has included some [new calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944339%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to support this functionality:

```
HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(T value) sends “application/json”
HttpClient.PostAsXmlAsync<T>(T value) sends “application/xml”
```

So, the new code ([from dunston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10305214/39758)) becomes:

```
Widget widget = new Widget()
widget.Name = "test"
widget.Price = 1;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44268");
client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/test", widget)
    .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() );
```

Comment: Yea, but what if you don't have access to the Widget class?

Comment: The new `HttpClient.PostAsXXXAsync<T>( T value ) methods are great, but what about one for application/x-www-form-urlencoded format? Is there a simple / short way for that or do we still need to create elaborate `KeyValuePair` lists?

Comment: You will still need to use KeyValuePair lists if you do not have a concrete class to pass in.

Comment: @Jaans [Flurl.Http](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http) provides a simple/short way via `PostUrlEncodedAsync`.

Comment: Note that you need to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting to be able to use `PostAsJsonAsync` or `PostAsXmlAsync`

Comment: To use the PostAsJsonAcync, add the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client !!

Answer (score 99):

You should use the `SendAsync` method instead, this is a generic method, that serializes the input to the service

```
Widget widget = new Widget()
widget.Name = "test"
widget.Price = 1;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44268/api/test");
client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage<Widget>(widget))
    .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() );
```

If you don't want to create the concrete class, you can make it with the `FormUrlEncodedContent` class

```
var client = new HttpClient();

// This is the postdata
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "test"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Price ", "100"));

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData); 

client.PostAsync("http://localhost:44268/api/test", content).ContinueWith(
    (postTask) =>
    {
        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    });
```

Note: you need to make your id to a nullable int (`int?`)

Comment: This will be called from an external project, where I will not have a reference to the assembly that contains the Widget object. I tried creating an anonymously typed object that contains the correct properties, serializing it using this method, and passing it that way, but I get a 500 Internal Server Error. It never hits the web api controller method.

Comment: Oh - then you need to post xml, or json to the webapi service, and it will deserialize it - it does the same, SendAsync, is serializing the object for the service

Comment: You lost me at new HttpRequestMessage<ValuesController>(this). I'm not sure how to construct the HttpRequestMessage with the jsonified value. I tried setting requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(widget)); but it still doesn't like it. It gives me an internal server error - same result.

Comment: Have just made a update - i have testet the code, but with some simpler code, but i should work

Comment: Hooray! That is getting me the results I need. Thank you!

Comment: Just in case someone else has the same question, I have something to add to the SendAsync code above. You need to add a second parameter to the HttpRequestMessage ctor so that web api can serialize the message. You also have to set the request type. Like so: `var message = HttpRequestMessage<Widget>(widget, "application/json"); 
message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;` And then you can just call `client.SendAsync(message)`

Comment: I'm getting "The non-generic type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' cannot be used with type arguments". is this still valid?

Comment: Yeah the first solution does not work anymore:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350492

Comment: not work, because FormUrlEncodedContent is not "application/json"

Comment: "We have decided to remove HttpResponseMessage<T> as part of a larger redesign of how content negotiation works."

Answer (score 76):

Note that if you are using a Portable Class Library, **HttpClient will not have PostAsJsonAsync method**.
To post a content as JSON using a Portable Class Library, you will have to do this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(argsAsJson, Encoding.UTF8, 
"application/json");

await client.PostAsync(new Uri(wsUrl), contentPost).ContinueWith(
(postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
```

Comment: When argsAsJson comes from a serialized object, and this object has a property ie. Content = "domain\user", then the \ will be encoded twice. Once when serialized to argsAsJson and second time when PostAsync posts contentPost. How to avoid double encoding?

Comment: Excellent @fabiano ! This really did the trick. Those two extra arguments are necessary in this type of projects.

Comment: Very good @PeterKlein! I could not find this information within Microsoft's documentation over the web, so this can help others with the same problem. My project simply doesn't send data without this trick.

Comment: Note that you might also have to add "application/json" into the request's Accept header, per http://stackoverflow.com/a/40375351/3063273

Answer (score 3):

If you want the types of convenience methods mentioned in other answers but need portability (or even if you don't), you might want to check out [Flurl](https://flurl.io) [disclosure: I'm the author]. It (thinly) wraps `HttpClient` and Json.NET and adds some fluent sugar and other goodies, including some baked-in [testing helpers](https://flurl.io/docs/testable-http).

Post as JSON:

```
var resp = await "http://localhost:44268/api/test".PostJsonAsync(widget);
```

or URL-encoded:

```
var resp = await "http://localhost:44268/api/test".PostUrlEncodedAsync(widget);
```

Both examples above return an `HttpResponseMessage`, but Flurl includes extension methods for returning other things if you just want to cut to the chase:

```
T poco = await url.PostJsonAsync(data).ReceiveJson<T>();
dynamic d = await url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(data).ReceiveJson();
string s = await url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(data).ReceiveString();
```

Flurl is available on NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http
```

Answer (score 1):

After investigating lots of alternatives, I have come across another approach, suitable for the API 2.0 version.

(VB.NET is my favorite, sooo...)

```
Public Async Function APIPut_Response(ID as Integer, MyWidget as Widget) as Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
    Dim DesiredContent as HttpContent = New StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyWidget))
    Return Await APIClient.PutAsync(String.Format("api/widget/{0}", ID), DesiredContent)
End Function
```

Good luck! For me this worked out (in the end!).

Regards,
Peter

Comment: This WITH the suggestions given above by @Fabiano make things happen.

Comment: VB.NET is no ones favorite :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new Widget();
client.PostAsync<Widget>("http://localhost:44268/api/test", content, new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter())
    .ContinueWith((postTask) => { postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone like me didn't really understand what all above are talking about, I give an easy example which is working for me.
If you have a web api which url is "http://somesite.com/verifyAddress", it is a post method and it need you to pass it an address object. You want to call this api in your code. Here what you can do.

```
    public Address verifyAddress(Address address)
    {
        this.client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://somesite.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var urlParm = URL + "verifyAddress";
        response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(urlParm,address).Result;
        var dataObjects = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Address>().Result : null;
        return dataObjects;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wound up with, based upon the other answers here. This is for an HttpPost that receives and responds with complex types:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
                       strMyHttpPostURL,
                       new MyComplexObject { Param1 = param1, Param2 = param2}).ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
                    //debug:
                    //String s = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    MyOtherComplexType moct = (MyOtherComplexType)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, typeof(MyOtherComplexType));
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a service call like this:

```
public async void SaveActivationCode(ActivationCodes objAC)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(serviceAddress + "/SaveActivationCode" + "?apiKey=445-65-1216", objAC);
}
```

And Service method like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutSaveActivationCode(ActivationCodes objAC)
{
}
```

PutAsJsonAsync takes care of Serialization and deserialization over the network

Comment: This will send a HTTP PUT message, not a POST as requested. As others have said `PostAsJsonAsync` will send the requires data, as a POST in JSON.