# Post complex type formatted as form-url-encoded using ASP.Net HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to `HTTP POST` a complex type to a web service (which I don't controll). I believe the web service was built using an older version of ASP.NET MVC. It model binds payloads formatted as `form-url-encoded`.

If I fire the following at it, it works perfectly. As you can see, I've manually created a collection of key/value pairs.

```
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", "some-username"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "some-password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Product", "some-product")
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = new HttpClient().PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

But I don't want to have to do this, I just want to send complex types if I can.

```
var content = new ComplexType("some-username", "some-password", "some-product");

var response = new HttpClient().PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

I believe there used to be a `HttpRequestMessage<T>` but that's been dropped in favour of

`HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(T value) sends “application/json”
HttpClient.PostAsXmlAsync<T>(T value) sends “application/xml”`

But I don't want to send `Json` or `XML` I want to send `form-url-ecncoded` without the hassle of converting complex types to collections of key/value pairs.

Essentially I'd also like to know the answer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304863/how-to-use-system-net-httpclient-to-post-a-complex-type)  that Jaans poses (His is the second comment to the second answer).

Can anyone advise please.

Comment: Web API does have a `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter`, but this formatter cannot "write" and only can "read". So, Web API doesn't have out of box support for this.

Comment: That's a real shame. Anyone know of a decent work around?

Comment: You can probably take a look at a custom formatter from Carlos: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-cda3c9a7, but this talks about converting from JObject to FormUrlEncoded. I don't like suggesting this, but you can probably convert your complextype to a JObject using Json.net serializer and then convert this JObject to formurlencoded as suggested in the link.

Comment: That could be the way to go. Thanks Kiran

Answer (score 2):

[Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http) [disclosure: I'm the author] provides a method that seems to be exactly what you're looking for:

```
using Flurl.Http;

var resp = await url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new {
    Username = "some-username",
    Password = "some-password",
    Product = "some-product",
});
```

Flurl is small and portable, and uses `HttpClient` under the hood. It is available via NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've almost got a solution that does work, I'd say just go with it. Organize your code inside an extension method so that you can post using that, something like:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsFormUrlEncodedAsync<T>(
    this HttpClient httpClient, T value)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Your implementation just needs to serialize your object into form-encoded values, which you should be able to do easily with reflection.

Then you can call the code exactly as you would for JSON or XML.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
var content = new ComplexType("some-username", "some-password", "some-product");

var response = new HttpClient().PostAsync<ComplexType>(url, content, new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
```

Comment: This looks like exactly like what I was hoping for. I could be wrong ,but I don't think this functionality was available when I posed the question originally. Otherwise why would @ToddMenier have written his Flurl library?  That said, thanks for your answer, it may help others going forward.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` does not serialize arbitrary types. You have to either use another library, `FormUrlEncodedContent` or use reflection