# Sending Commands from an MVC4 site to Another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have two sites: one of them controls the other sending some commands through Web API. The idea is: the action of the controller site sends a command to the other site, gets the response and perform some business rules, without redirecting to the other site.

I have tons of examples explaining how to implement this via jQuery, but I want to make the controller post the data to the other site, instead of the view.

I found an approach at this answer: [How to use System.Net.HttpClient to post a complex type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304863/how-to-use-system-net-httpclient-to-post-a-complex-type), but I want the answer for an JSON approach.

Can someone post a simple example using JSON showing how to do this?

Comment: You'll need to add some details about what you're trying to do here. How do you mean "post data to the other site"? It feels like you're moving away from the controller's single responsibility - accept user interaction and present a View. You can't `RedirectToAction` to another site, obviously, as they would sit in different app domains.

Comment: @ChrisHardie answer updated as requested.

Comment: Ah, you need to, I believe, massage your model. I think your question is more like: "How do I post to a Web API endpoint using JSON from C#". Perhaps try this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/05/how-to-use-httpclient-to-post-json-data.aspx

Comment: Bingo, but I found this article a bit prolix. What I want is a simple step-by-step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't find a brief answer to my question, I'll post the solution I've made.

As the method uses an `HttpClient` method that requires `async` statements, the action below was implemented retuning a `Task<ActionResult>`. Another modification is if you're saving an object in context.

Instead of using:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

You'll have to use:

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The code below implements an Action from an ASP.NET MVC4 Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Logic to save the model.
        // I usually reload saved data using something kind of the statement below:

        var inserted = context.MyModels
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(m => m.SomeCondition == someVariable)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        // Send Command.
        // APIMyModel is a simple class with public properties.
        var apiModel = new APIMyModel();

        apiModel.AProperty = inserted.AProperty;
        apiModel.AnotherProperty = inserted.AnotherProperty;

        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(APIMyModel));

        // use the serializer to write the object to a MemoryStream 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        jsonSer.WriteObject(ms, apiModel);
        ms.Position = 0;

        //use a Stream reader to construct the StringContent (Json) 
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        // Note if the JSON is simple enough you could ignore the 5 lines above that do the serialization and construct it yourself 
        // then pass it as the first argument to the StringContent constructor 
        StringContent theContent = new StringContent(sr.ReadToEnd(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 

        HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
        Uri theUri = new Uri("http://yoursite/api/TheAPIAction");
        HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);

        if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Success Logic. Yay!
        }
        else
        {
            // show the response status code 
            String failureMsg = "HTTP Status: " + aResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + " - Reason: " + aResponse.ReasonPhrase;
        } 

        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    // if Model is not valid, you can put your logic to reload ViewBag properties here.
}
```