# Post Method in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-post

I need to send some parameters to a php server using post method in WP8 app and get response in json format. I've tried everything that I found on stackoverflow and other sites, still could not.

The last code piece I come up with is:

```
public static async void GetData(string url, string data)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), new StringContent(data));

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(responseBody); // just showing the response for now
}
```

It shows a message from the server (which is an error stating some fields are missing) that it actually communicates with the server but the problem is with sending data. I call the above method like:

```
GetData("http_address_here", "?action=REGISTER&email=asc@fsdf.com&password=54561wefwe&firstname=sdfsdf&lastname=sdfsdf&picture=10");
```

But I saw an example sending data in xml. Possibly the mistake is about calling the method. Having seen tens of sample codes and trying everything, I really got confused about it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not POST'ing the data, you are doing a GET, this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304863/how-to-use-system-net-httpclient-to-post-a-complex-type

Comment: The documentation provided to me to develop the app says: "All parameters are passed via POST method". At least I tried to POST. But what do you mean? Am I doing a GET in the above code or the thing I need is GET?

Comment: When you pass your parameters in the URL those are GET parameters, POST parameters become writen in the main body of the request. Look at the previous link, there is an example on how to POST parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code:                                                             var client = new HttpClient();
    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "test"));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Price ", "100"));
    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData); 
    client.PostAsync("http://localhost:44268/api/test", content).ContinueWith(
    (postTask) =>
    {
        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }); It works. How can I get the response(showing on screen.)

Comment: you can get the response from string responseBodyAsText = await postTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: @JagathMurali Adding that line causes the following error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to solve the problem. Thanks everyone for helping. The working code is below, it uses POST method and the resulting json object is stored as a string.

```
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", "qewfwef"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "qewfwef"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("firstname", "qewfwef"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("lastname", "qewfwef"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("picture", "123456")
                };

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        MessageBox.Show(responseString.ToString()); // just to see what we get
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
public static async Task<string> SendRequestPostResponse()
    {
        try
        {
            var postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your Url Here");

            postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; // Whichever content type you want to POST
            postRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var requestStream = await postRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                byte[] postDataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your data here"); // Data for the POST request here
                await requestStream.WriteAsync(postDataArray, 0, postDataArray.Length);
            }

            WebResponse postResponse = await postRequest.GetResponseAsync();

            if (postResponse != null)
            {
                var postResponseStream = postResponse.GetResponseStream();
                var postStreamReader = new StreamReader(postResponseStream);

                string response = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                return response;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: GetRequestStreamAsync(), GetResponseAsync() gives:  'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition ... And what is "sessionCookie"?

Comment: I found that GetRequestStreamAsync() and GetResponseAsync() are not available in Windows Phone 8. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I am using that in my application. May be your .net framework is 4 and not 4.5

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststreamasync.aspx - this page says, Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Silverlight 8.1. Maybe your project is for Windows Phone 8.1? (Though Windows Phone 8 is in the list of "Platforms", I don't know what it exactly means)

Comment: below that in under platform section its says Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8. And i am using this in my app which is windows phone 7.1. if you see the .net frame work its only available in the 4.5 version only

Comment: .Net framework 4.5 is isntalled on the machine but I do not know how to check app's framework version, if it might differ. Do you know the way to check or change the version?

Comment: I had 4.5 .net framework when I created the WP Project. So i think (i don't know exactly) it will take the latest .net version

Answer (score 0):

HTTPWebRequest would be another alternative.