# Post complex data type using HttpClient

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, dotnet-httpclient

> I need to post an object of class like>

```
    class A{
        public string dataitem1{get;set;}
        public byte[] dataitem2{get;set;}

 }
```

> I need to post the object of this class to webAPI using Windows Store App 8.1. I tried many solutions but could not find anyone working. Can somebody provide help by code or link to working demo. I'm trying to implement full MVVM structure
>
> [I Found one demo here but not working in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304863/how-to-use-system-net-httpclient-to-post-a-complex-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By converting the object into a json string you can transfer the json object.

You can use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

Then you can return the object from webapi.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but in 8.1 instead of this JSON.Net has to be used but this resolved my problem. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Updated my knowledge as well.