# Replace WebClient.UploadString() to HttpClient.PostAsync

Tags: c#, post, httpclient, webclient

I want to replace WebClient to HttpClient in my code. What HttpContent I have to use in HttpClient to replace WebClient.UploadString?
My WebClient code:

```
string data = string.Format("name={0}&warehouse={1}&address={2}", name, shop.Warehouse.Id, shop.Address);

using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    string fullUrl = BaseUrl + url;
    string response = wc.UploadString(fullUrl, data);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you're building on ASP WebForms, it is very inadvisable to switch from WebClient to HttpClient. 
With WebClient, you'll not have to create Async issues because none of the calls would be awaitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct your postdata and use it in the instance of the FormUrlEncodedContent like so:

```
// This is the postdata
var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "test"));

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
```

There are solutions specified on this page:

[How to use System.Net.HttpClient to post a complex type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304863/how-to-use-system-net-httpclient-to-post-a-complex-type)

You can decide on posting it asynchronously or synchronously for example:

```
HttpResponseMessage x = await httpClient.PostAsync(fullUrl, content);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also replace

```
string payload = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("e:\\IIF-Input3 (1).xml");
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string res = client.UploadString("http://1.2.3.4:80/RunJson?name=Test", "POST", payload);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

with

```
string payload = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("e:\\IIF-Input3 (1).xml");
var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(payload, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://1.2.3.4:80/");
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("/RunJson?name=Test", content).Result;

        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```