# How can I convert a json string containing the contents of a generic list of a custom class to FormUrlEncodedContent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, httpresponse

I can pass some bogus/test data to a Web API method like so:

```
string dataAsJson = "[{\"ItemDescription\": \"DUCKBILLS, GRAMPS-EIER 70CT  42#\",\"PackagesMonth1\": 1467}]";
String uriToCall = String.Format("/api/produceusage/{0}/{1}/{2}", _unit, beginRange, endRange);
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", dataAsJson)
});
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriToCall, content);
```

The test data is received at the server just fine.

However, I need to pass more complex data than a simple array of KeyValuePair - a generic list of a custom class. In the code below, _dtDelPerf is a List

```
string dataAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dtDelPerf);
String uriToCall = String.Format("/api/deliveryperformance/{0}/{1}/{2}", _unit, _beginDateYYYYMMDD, _endDateYYYYMMDD); 
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    //new List<DeliveryPerformance>("", dataAsJson)
    new List<DeliveryPerformance>(dataAsJson)
});
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriToCall, content);
```

Neither the commented-out attempt ("new List("", dataAsJson)") nor the one below it work. With the first, I got several compile errors, such as, "*'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments'*"

With the second, after removing the first arg so that it's:

```
new List<DeliveryPerformanceClass>(dataAsJson)
```

...I get other compile errors, such as, "*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'*"

What do I need to do to push this data through?

Comment: I think this got answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304863/how-to-use-system-net-httpclient-to-post-a-complex-type