# Send HTTP POST message in ASP.NET Core using HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to send dynamic object like

```
new { x = 1, y = 2 };
```

as body of HTTP POST message. So I try to write

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

but I can't find method

```
client.PostAsJsonAsync()
```

So I tried to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions package to project.json and add

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
```

to uses clause. However It didn't help me.

So what is the easiest way to send POST request with JSON body in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Wonder why this article does not contain an example for POST https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using .NET 5 or above, you can (and should) use the `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method from [System.Net.Http.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0):

```cs
httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, new { 
    x = 1, 
    y = 2 
});
```

If you are using an older version of .NET Core, you can implement the extension function yourself:

```cs
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, object body)
    {
        var bodyJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(bodyJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 263):

You should add reference to "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" package (read [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20180328142748/http://dotnetliberty.com:80/index.php/2015/12/10/typed-extensions-for-httpclient-on-net-core) for samples).

Without any additional extension, you may use standard `PostAsync` method:

```
client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

where `jsonInString` value you can get by calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(<your object>);`

Comment: But Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client doesn't look like ASP.NET Core RC2 library. And the secon way is really too much of code repetition((

Comment: @Rem why don't you create an `HttpClient`  extension method(`PostAsJsonAsync`) to use the second way. It enables you to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Sure. But I asked the question in order find out am I missing something. I can't believe it hasn't been implemented in Core yet!

Comment: This library isn't a core/.net-standard one, I don't think System.Net.Http.Formatting has been ported yet

Comment: This will work for HttpClient created by IHttpClientFactory in .NET Core 2.2 from the nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Http. However, how do you do it this way but add headers such as an authorization key.

Answer (score 123):

I use this class:

```
public class JsonContent : StringContent
{
    public JsonContent(object obj) :
        base(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    { }
}
```

Sample of usage:

```
new HttpClient().PostAsync("http://...", new JsonContent(new { x = 1, y = 2 }));
```

Comment: Why not an extension method? public static class JsonContent { public Task<?> PostAsJSonAsync(this HttpClient client, object toSerializeAsJson) { ... } }

Comment: I like the JsonContent class approach

Comment: Does this set `Content-Length:` HTTP header?

Comment: @VyacheslavNapadovsky it depends on `HttpClient` settings, e.g. if one set `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true` `Content-Length` header wouldn't be set and [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) would be set instead. However, if one creates the client like `var client = new HttpClient();`, the header `Content-Length` would be set for this content class by default.

Answer (score 13):

I would add to the accepted answer that you would also want to add the `Accept` header to the `httpClient`:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft now recommends using an `IHttpClientFactory` with the following benefits:

- Provides a central location for naming and configuring logical
  `HttpClient` instances. For example, a client named github could be
  registered and configured to access GitHub. A default client can be
  registered for general access.
- Codifies the concept of outgoing middleware via delegating handlers
  in `HttpClient`. Provides extensions for Polly-based middleware to take
  advantage of delegating handlers in `HttpClient`.
- Manages the pooling and lifetime of underlying
  `HttpClientMessageHandler` instances. Automatic management avoids
  common DNS (Domain Name System) problems that occur when manually
  managing `HttpClient` lifetimes.
- Adds a configurable logging experience (via `ILogger`) for all requests
  sent through clients created by the factory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Setup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
        // Remaining code deleted for brevity.
```

POST example:

```
public class BasicUsageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public BasicUsageModel(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
    
    public async Task CreateItemAsync(TodoItem todoItem)
    {
        var todoItemJson = new StringContent(
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(todoItem, _jsonSerializerOptions),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");
            
        var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        
        using var httpResponse =
            await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/TodoItems", todoItemJson);
    
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#make-post-put-and-delete-requests

Comment: What is the `_jsonSerializerOptions` part? Do you know if any options need to be set?

Comment: @Lukas See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0
Microsoft has it in their example code but try without and see what happens. :)

Comment: Here is an article by Microsoft showing use of IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this has long since been implemented in .NET Core.

At the time of writing (September 2019), the `project.json` file of NuGet 3.x+ has been superseded by `PackageReference` (as explained at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/archive/project-json).

To get access to the `*Async` methods of the `HttpClient` class, your `.csproj` file must be correctly configured.

Open your `.csproj` file in a plain text editor, and make sure the first line is
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`
(as pointed out at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#the-csproj-format).

To get access to the `*Async` methods of the `HttpClient` class, you also need to have the correct **package reference** in your `.csproj` file, like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

(See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference.
Also: *We recommend applications targeting ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage*, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage)

Methods such as `PostAsJsonAsync`, `ReadAsAsync`, `PutAsJsonAsync` and `DeleteAsync` should now work out of the box. (No using directive needed.)

**Update:** The PackageReference tag is no longer needed in .NET Core 3.0.

Comment: I couldn't manage to get PostAsJsonAsync to work with .NET Core 3.1. Thanks