# Where is the PostAsJsonAsync method in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, coreclr

I was looking for the `PostAsJsonAsync()` extension method in ASP.NET Core. [Based on this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180914182339/http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/12/10/typed-extensions-for-httpclient-on-net-core/), it's available in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` assembly.

I had thought Microsoft had changed all of the assembly names from `Microsoft.AspNet` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore` to be more specific to .NET Core, however, and yet I cannot find an `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebApi.Client` assembly.

Where is the `PostAsJsonAsync()` extension method in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: It's not part of the ASP.NET Core project, hence not following the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` naming schema. It's originally an extension for Windows 8/81./10/UWP/WinRT applications, which are based on `System.Runtime` and .NET Core is based on it too

Comment: so that extension is not available in .Net Core out of the box?

Comment: Unless you add this package to your project, nope its not available. It's `HttpClient` extension. Completely unrelated to ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core. As seen https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/ here it has no dependencies on neither ASP.NET MVC5 nor on ASP.NET Core MVC. It should work with .NET Core though, as it's a PCL which targets :NET 4.5 and Win8/8.1. You just need the `"import": [ "portable-net45+win8" ]` statement in project.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send HTTP POST message in ASP.NET Core using HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750451/send-http-post-message-in-asp-net-core-using-httpclient-postasjsonasync)

Answer (score 63):

It comes as part of the library `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/

Comment: I guess this should be the correct answer now. The package is available and supporting .Net standard 2.0

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client does not apply to .net Core

Comment: This worked for me (gave me access to the [action]AsJsonAsync() functions... My follow-up question is "should that be the solution?" Are their reasons one should not do it this way? I have a .NET core library that is being updated/ported from .Net4.8 projects to be .NetCore 2.0... and this library needs to interface with other APIs external... So it needs an http client... and the old code is working in .net4.8... just because it works doesn't always mean its the right way to do it going forward. I'd like to hear about that if anyone knows offhand why I shouldn't do it this way... 
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 57):

I dont deserve any credit for this. Have a look @danroth27 answer in the following link.

> https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/mvc/controllers/testing/sample/TestingControllersSample/tests/TestingControllersSample.Tests/IntegrationTests/HttpClientExtensions.cs

He uses an extension method. Code as below. (Copied from the above github link). I am using it on .Net Core 2.0.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestingControllersSample.Tests.IntegrationTests
{
    public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(
            this HttpClient httpClient, string url, T data)
        {
            var dataAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var content = new StringContent(dataAsString);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
        }

        public static async Task<T> ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpContent content)
        {
            var dataAsString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(dataAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That link no longer works. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26233 Like the highly voted comment above, Microsoft now recommends the NuGet package.

Answer (score 20):

As of **.NET 5.0**, this has been (re)introduced as an extension method off of `HttpClient`, via the `System.Net.Http.Json` namespace. See the [`HttpClientJsonExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0) class for details.

#### Demonstration

It works something like the following:

```cs
var httpClient  = new HttpClient();
var url         = "https://StackOverflow.com"
var data        = new MyDto();
var source      = new CancellationTokenSource();

var response    = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<MyDto>(url, data, source.Token);
```

And, of course, you'll need to reference some namespaces:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;          //HttpClient, HttpResponseMessage
using System.Net.Http.Json;     //HttpClientJsonExtensions
using System.Threading;         //CancellationToken
using System.Threading.Tasks;   //Task
```

Alternatively, if you're using the [.NET 6 SDK's implicit `using` directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#implicit-using-directives), three of these will be included for you, so you'll just need:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;     //HttpClientJsonExtensions
```

#### Background

This is based on [the design document](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/json-http-extensions/json-http-extentions.md), which was previously [referenced by @erandac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60675630/3025856)—though the design has since changed, particularly for the `PostAsJsonAsync()` method.

Obviously, this doesn't solve the problem for anyone still using .NET Core, but with [.NET 5.0 released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/), this is now the best option.

Comment: This solution also works for .NET Core 3.0 and newer. You need to add NuGet package `System.Net.Http.Json`

Answer (score 11):

That is not part of the ASP.NET Core project. However you can proceed with:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://myurl/api");

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);

request.Content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {                
    }
else
    {
    }
```

Comment: Remember to dispose the request and http variables.

Answer (score 9):

You Can Use This Extension for use PostAsJsonAsync method in ASP.NET core

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, T data)
    {
        var dataAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var content = new StringContent(dataAsString);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, T data)
    {
        var dataAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var content = new StringContent(dataAsString);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return httpClient.PutAsync(url, content);
    }

    public static async Task<T> ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpContent content)
    {
        var dataAsString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(dataAsString);
    }
}
```

see: [httpclient-extensions](https://jonlabelle.com/snippets/view/csharp/httpclient-extensions)

Answer (score 6):

this is coming late but I think it may help someone down the line. So the `*AsJsonAsync()` methods are not part of the ASP.NET Core project. I created a package that gives you the functionality. You can get it on Nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Http.Extensions

```
using AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
...
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.PostAsJsonAsync('url', payload);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Nuget package `System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension` to your project.

Or you can use

```
client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Comment: The question was specifically around the helper method `PostAsJsonAsync`

Answer (score 2):

The method`PostAsJsonAsync` (along with other `*Async` methods of the
`HttpClient` class) is indeed available out of the box – without using
directives.

Your `.csproj` file should start with
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`, and contain the lines

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have given [a more elaborated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169080) to a similar question.

(The PackageReference is no longer needed in .NET Core 3.0.)

Answer (score 2):

To follow on from the answers above, I have a small addition that was required for me to get it to work.

Previously I was using a .NET Core 2.1 web app using the `PostAsJsonAsync()` method, and when I upgraded to .NET Core 3.1 it no longer worked.

I could not get the above answers to work, and it turned out to be because the text to be posted had to be surrounded by quotes, and any quotes within it had to be escaped. I made the following extension method, which solved my problem:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync(this HttpClient client, string uri, string json)
{
    //For some reason, not doing this will cause it to fail:
    json = $"\"{json.Replace("\"", "\\\"")}\"";

    return await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

Note that I am using the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` as opposed to the Newtonsoft version.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in a standard 2.0 library

[System.Net.Http.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Json)

Answer (score 0):

make the extension method truly async:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(
    this HttpClient httpClient, string url, T data)
{
    var dataAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var content = new StringContent(dataAsString);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    return await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use PostJsonAsync, PutJsonAsync or any other json extension methods in Blazor you need to add a following statement

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet core 3.x runtime itself going to have set of extension methods for HttpClient which uses System.Text.Json Serializer

https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/json-http-extensions/json-http-extensions.md

Answer (score 0):

If you are in 2021 and having .Net Core 3.1, make sure in your project file csproj, Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is upto date, the latest is 2.2.8. You can check and update the package as below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

then restore your project from cli like this:

```
dotnet restore
```

Comment: How does this relate to the `PostAsJsonAsync()` method? It's unclear how this addresses this question.