# Getting the response of Asynchronous http web request using POST method in asp.net core

Tags: c#, rest, post, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core. I am able to get the response from the http webrequest using GET method. To get the response via http webrequest using POST am facing 405 error.(Remote server not found)
Here is my code using GET Method.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = MakeAsyncRequest("http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/flow/status", "text/html");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static Task<string> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, string contentType)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = contentType;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Proxy = null;

            Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                request.BeginGetResponse,
                asyncResult => request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
                (object)null);

            return task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result));
        }

        private static string ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response)
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                string results = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results))
                {
                    Data data = new Data();
                   data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(results);
                }
                return results;
            }
        }
```

Please let me know how to get the response using async POST method in asp.net core. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may use HttpClient class to make requests easier. Look into http://stackoverflow.com/q/37750451/2833802

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/flow/status", new StringContent("Json string", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```