# .Net Core post form data to uri

Tags: asp.net-core

How do you post form data to an external url in .Net Core?  For example, if I wanted to recreate this sample request:

```
POST 
Url: www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=ABCD1234&
client_secret=XYZ1234&
redirect_uri=https://test.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750451/send-http-post-message-in-asp-net-core-using-httpclient-postasjsonasync) that shows an example for posting JSON, but nothing for form data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be done with `HttpClient` from *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client* package as well by using `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", "4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7") },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "ABCD1234") },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "XYZ1234") },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "https://test.example.com/code") },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code") },
};

client.PostAsync("www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueCollection));
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile but it works when you fix it.  You have to do `new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "ABCD1234"),` to initialize the list.  If you want to make that edit, then I will accept, the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @big_water Fixed, my fault for being hasty :D