# Send HTTP requests using .NET core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

my question can sound quite simple or silly, I think it too, but I can't find what I need.

The only post I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750451/send-http-post-message-in-asp-net-core-using-httpclient-postasjsonasync), but the linked page in the accepted answer refers to .NET core 1, while I need the version 2.0. Also Google, this time, is not my friend.

I have a ASP.NET CORE 2.0 project. Sometimes, it needs to send HTTP requests to some API. So, I need to understand how can I do HTTP requests using .NET core 2.0.

Do you have some snippets or some links I can study about it? How can I send a HTTP request? And, further, how can I insert some data in its body? Probabaly I have to use HttpClient library, right?

Comment: If you want to make Http requests you would use the HttpClient class.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It's always the same. You use `HttpClient`. There's literally a ton of stuff online in that regard, so just confine your queries to that.

Comment: Ok, I thought there were some differences from the classic .NET framework. Thanks for the feedback ;)

Comment: With the upcoming 2.1 release you can use the HttpClientFactory that manages some stuff for you. Take a look here: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory

Comment: @MuqeetKhan good. Do you know when it will be released? Or it is already available?

Comment: What kind of background knowledge makes you feel that 2.0 is not backward compatible with 1.x.

Comment: HttpClient is available since .NET 4.5. The API is the same.

Comment: @LexLi just a doubt, it happens. It'd be too silly don't have never a douby, do you agree?

Comment: Did you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2