# Consuming Asp.Net Web API from Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Web API project and I am trying to call some of the API(s) from an ASP.net Core application. The code is like below:

```
var connectionViewModel = new ConnectionViewModel()
        {
            ConnectionId = connectionId,
            MemberId = Guid.Parse(memberId),
            ReconnectOn = DateTime.Now
        };

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63892/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/app/chat/connection/PostConnection", connectionViewModel).Result;

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

and here is the web api

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostConnection(ConnectionViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var validation = await connectionService.CreateConnection(viewModel);

        if (validation.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok(resultSet.CreateResultSet(validation));
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(validation.Message);
        }
    }
```

the problem is view Model is always null.
I use the same code to call the web api from console application or another web api application and it works fine. But it does not work when I use inside asp.net core application.

Thanks

Comment: It can't be the same exact code (or POST data) if it works in other applications. Is `connectionViewModel` from the same assembly as what the API is using?   If not, does it have the same exact properties?

Comment: _Where_ is it null? `connectionViewModel` vs `viewModel`?

Comment: Yes, connectionViewModel is from the same assembly

Comment: viewModel in the PostConnection action is null.(input parameter) @EdSF

Comment: Have you tried explicitly serializing ConnectionViewModel before adding it as a parameter using NewtonSoft?

Comment: If the  viewModel in the action method of `Task<IHttpActionResult> PostConnection(ConnectionViewModel viewModel)` is always null , it indicates that the binding to viewModel  doesn't take place as expected.  You'd better check what the exact request is when the request has been sent to the action method .

Comment: I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750451/send-http-post-message-in-asp-net-core-using-httpclient-postasjsonasync) the correct answer.