# POST request in NET Core (C#) from python to C#

Tags: c#, python, .net-core, request

```
import requests

requests.post('https://dathost.net/api/0.1/game-servers/54f55784ced9b10646653aa9/start',
              auth=('john@doe.com', 'secretPassword'))
```

How would one write this in C#? (NET Core)

Comment: This could be a good starting point [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: I this this is what you want:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37751250/2057653

Comment: I tried it but I could not get how to do auth=('email','password') this part.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of the added comments, I would recommend using a library called [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).
You can easily find the nuget package and the code will be as easier as:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://dathost.net");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("john@doe.com", "secretPassword");

var request = new RestRequest("api/0.1/game-servers/{id}/start", Method.POST);
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "54f55784ced9b10646653aa9");

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

You can also do async requests:

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HttpClient.

Add usings top of your code first.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

And run this code wherever you want.

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("john@doe.com:secretPassword");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

    var response = await client.PostAsync(
        "https://dathost.net/api/0.1/game-servers/54f55784ced9b10646653aa9/start", null);
```

Hope this helps.