# PUT request working in vb.net but not in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, vb.net, http-put

I am developing a REST client in C# that performs the following operation:

1. It sends a POST request to the server with a query string parameter PolicyId=myhotp and this json data {"uid":"*name*"}.
2. The server responds with json data with state id like this {"state":"323434j2hj"}
3. I extract the value of "state" from the received json data and send
   it in another PUT request to the same server with OTP in order to verify. stateid is sent as query string parameter StateId=ihhfueh8f88 and otp is sent as json data {"otp":"123456"}. The server verifies OTP against state id.

But the server responds that the stateid is invalid. Irony is that this same procedure works when I use old way i.e. Microsoft.XMLHTTP to make requests but it doesn't work with HTTP Client. I am not able to transfer state id in query string. 
Here is my code using HTTP Client:

```
        User user = new User();
        user.uid = "username";
        String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        MessageBox.Show(json);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://fqdn");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        var response = client.PostAsync("api?myhotp", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        MessageBox.Show(contents);
        var obj = JObject.Parse(contents);
        string id = (string)obj["state"];
        MessageBox.Show(id);
        Otp otpObj = new Otp();
        otpObj.otp = "123456";
        String jsonotp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(otpObj);
        MessageBox.Show(jsonotp);
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://fqdn");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        response = client.PutAsync("api?StateId="+id, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        MessageBox.Show(contents);
```

Here is the code with Microsoft.XMLHTTP:

```
       Type xmlType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        dynamic objXML = Activator.CreateInstance(xmlType);
        objXML.Open("POST", "http://fqdn/api?PolicyId=myhotp", false);
        objXML.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        objXML.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        //objXML.setOption(2, 13056);
        objXML.Send(json);
        MessageBox.Show(objXML.status.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(objXML.responseText.ToString());
        var obj = JObject.Parse(objXML.responseText.ToString());
        String id = (String)obj["state"];
        MessageBox.Show(id);
        Otp otpObj = new Otp();
        otpObj.otp = "123456";
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(otpObj);
        MessageBox.Show(json);
        objXML.Open("PUT", "http://fqdn/api?StateId="+id, false);
        objXML.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        objXML.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        objXML.Send(json);
        MessageBox.Show(objXML.status.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(objXML.responseText.ToString());
```

Comment: might be url is different.

Comment: I have tested this in VB.net with same URL.

Comment: URLs and Json are handled by classes, not the language itself. If there is any problem, it's the code itself, or the server that returns different results. *Reduce* your code to the simplest examples that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: PS. Generating Json by hand is extremely error prone and definitely **slower** than using a parser like Json.NET - string concatenation creates a lot of temporary strings, which results in memory and CPU waste *and* excess garbage collections (thus more CPU waste).

Comment: XMLHTTP?????? Why? Your VB.NET code isn't using .NET code (ie WebClient or HttpClient) to call the server? The two snippets are completely different

Comment: I suggest you drop the attempt at migrating from what looks like VBA, not VB.NET, and actually write proper .NET code. You shouldn't need more than 10-15 lines to serialize to Json *and* post. Create a class with the properties you want and just call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass)`. Also check HttpClient, the replacement of WebClient.

Comment: BTW your VB code has some serious bugs, like using `On Error Resume Next` to effectively *disable* error handling. Exceptions are ignored unless you remember to check for an error number, which is *not* error handling. There is no error handling in your code, ie `Try/Catch` blocks

Comment: Yes XMLHTTP in VB.NET. Is there a replacement for alternative to XMLHTTP in C#. This could help me in migrating. Till then, I will focus on writing proper .net code with HttpClient and JSON Serializer.

Comment: Yes error handling is not done. Actually this is just development environment at the moment. Once I complete my testing then I will go for error handling. I am confused that I am sending the correct state id in query string but still it gives error. Can there be some hidden characters?

Comment: @jahanzaib91 XMLHTTP is not .NET. You are creating a COM object, something that was only done in the VBA days. Since 2002 people use WebClient.

Comment: Anyway, posting an object as Json is as simple as calling the [PostAsJsonAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx), eg, `var response=await client.PostAsJsonAsync(someUrl,myObject);`

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot @PanagiotisKanavos. I am confused about which one to use from WebClient, WebRequest and HttpClient. Which is the latest and most used?

Comment: WebRequest is the base abstract class used by the clients. WebClient is the old class, created for simple FTP and HTTP calls. HttpClient is the latest class specifically created to makey using REST APis easy.

Comment: Check [How to use System.Net.HttpClient to post a complex type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304863/how-to-use-system-net-httpclient-to-post-a-complex-type)

Comment: Ok. I am checking it and developing a fresh .net code with JSON Serializer and HTTP Client. I will surely get back to you :). One thing more, I have seen some codes using RestSharp, how about using that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have developed the fresh code using HTTP Client and JsonConvert but I am still getting the same issue. I am getting the error of invalid id from server.

Comment: Can there be any issue during string concatenation? I am using the '+' operator. When I get the state id from json response, I add that to the query string using '+' operator, and that may be inserts some hidden characters or something?

Comment: There are no ghosts in .NET. The operator is part of .NET, not a specific language. If your URL is wrong, it's wrong. Since you didn't post what you do now, it's impossible to help. Use Fiddler or Postman to build and send the requests by hand to verify that they are correct. You can also use Fiddler to see what is *really* sent to the server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have sent and received requests using HTTP Requester (Firefox plugin) and everything is smooth. I have implemented it using Microsoft.XMLHTTP as well (I have edited the question). But the same URL isn't transfering the state id using HTTPClient. I have edited the question with the new description and code kindly check.

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain the problem very explicitly. _"doesn't work [...] I am not able to transfer state id"_ is not answerable.

Comment: @jahanzaib91 I don't see anything here that *can* be checked. Just several dozens of lines of code that do what should only be a couple of lines. I mean, why do you create `HttpClient` *twice*? Why *didn't* you use `PostAsJsonAsync`? HttpClient isn't broken either. If you get a different response, it's because the request was different. Use **Fiddler** to see what is actually sent and received

Comment: This sentence of yours did the trick "I mean, why do you create HttpClient twice". Actually I thought that we have to generate a fresh client variable for each request and here I was wrong. I removed the second initialization and it worked like a charm! It must be storing something with previous request (session) I guess? And when I initialized the variable again, the request history was lost. Thanks a lot all the credit goes to you. I am really thankful!